# In Matlab, combine data into bins of a given value

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I want to combine data into bins of a given value.

For example, say I have the following data

```
data = [rand(50,1) rand(50,1)*10];
data = sortrows(data,2);
```

Here, the first column is y values and the second column is x data. Now I want to take a mean (and quartiles) of the y data for bins of x of a value of, say 3, for example.

I think this is how I do it for bins of 1 but what if I want bins of value n?

```
m = accumarray(floor(data(:,2))+1, data(:,1), [], @mean);
l = accumarray(floor(data(:,2))+1, data(:,1), [], @(x) quantile(x,.25));
u = accumarray(floor(data(:,2))+1, data(:,1), [], @(x) quantile(x,.75));
```

So the data should be a matrix of 4 columns: mean, lower, upper and bins. The 4th column for bins of value 3 would be: 0 3 6 9...

I don't think this is correct:

```
result = [m l u (0:numel(m)-1).'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the first input to `accumarray` by the following (just divide `data(:,2)` by `n`):

```
floor(data(:,2)/n)+1
```

And the last column would be

```
(0:n:max(data(:,2))).'
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a small inline function to solve these problems:

```
binFun     = @(fun,data,bins) cellfun(@(val) fun(data(ismember(bins,val))), num2cell(unique(bins)));
```

usage:

```
m = binFun(@mean,round(data(:,2)),data(:,1));
```